# How to parse Json String in QT that contains object inside object

Tags: c++, qt

I am getting a JSON string format

```
"{\"bookHeavyInfo\":{\"Qty\":100},\"bookLightInfo\":{\"Qty\":2}}"
```

How can i extract the value of Qty for `bookHeavyInfo`
I am trying some thing like following

```
void parseJsonString(QString str)
{

 QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(str.toUtf8());

 QJsonObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.object();

 QString bookHeavyInfo= jsonObject["bookHeavyInfo"].toString();

}
```

I am not able to get value of `bookHeavyInfo`, and more specific how can I get the value of Qty . Please suggest

Comment: Exactly *how* does the code fail?  Pass in the address of a `QJsonParseError` to `fromJson`, and see what that says.  What is the result of `jsonResponse.isObject()`?  What is the return from `jsonObject["bookHeavyInfo"]` (before you convert to string?)

Answer (score 7):

Note that `bookHeavyInfo` is an object, so you can't use `toString` method for it.

Try this one instead:

```
QString str = "{\"bookHeavyInfo\":{\"Qty\":100},\"bookLightInfo\":{\"Qty\":2}}";
QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(str.toUtf8());

QJsonObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.object();

QJsonObject bookHeavyInfo = jsonObject["bookHeavyInfo"].toObject();

int qty = bookHeavyInfo["Qty"].toInt();
```